# Need to use sum using group by in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using Amazon Neptune and need to group result sets by an attribute "month" and perform a sum function on a calculation of 2 attributes.

The following query is used to project the calculation data using math step and monthName

```
g.V().hasLabel('Customer').out().hasLabel('Workspace')
.has('lastUpdatedOn').has('createdOn')
.project('gp1','var1','var2')
    .by(values('lastUpdatedOn_MN'))
    .by(values('createdOn'))
    .by(values('lastUpdatedOn'))
.project('mathResult','monthName')
    .by(math('var2-var1'))
    .by('gp1').fold()
```

The result for this is as below:

```
{
    'mathResult': 92111.0,
    'monthName': 'MARCH'
},
{
    'mathResult': 302648.0,
    'monthName': 'MARCH'
},
{
    'mathResult': 23820301.0,
    'monthName': 'FEBRUARY'
}
]
```

After that I group the result by the 'monthName' attribute from the projection like below

```
g.V().hasLabel('Customer').out().hasLabel('Workspace')
.has('lastUpdatedOn').has('createdOn')
.project('gp1','var1','var2')
    .by(values('lastUpdatedOn_MN'))
    .by(values('createdOn'))
    .by(values('lastUpdatedOn'))
.project('mathResult','monthName')
    .by(math('var2-var1'))
    .by('gp1')
.group().by('monthName').by('mathResult')
```

This results in the following output

```
{
    'MARCH': [
        92111.0,
        302648.0
    ],
    'FEBRUARY': [
        23820301.0
    ]
}
```

Please help me to get a result where in the above output instead of getting the list of numbers I can get a sum of the numbers in the list. I have used sum function but I am always getting error.

The way I am using the sum function is as below:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Customer').out().hasLabel('Workspace')
.has('lastUpdatedOn').has('createdOn')
.project('gp1','var1','var2')
    .by(values('lastUpdatedOn_MN'))
    .by(values('createdOn'))
    .by(values('lastUpdatedOn'))
.project('mathResult','monthName')
    .by(math('var2-var1'))
    .by('gp1')
.group().by('monthName').by(values('mathResult').sum())
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:root:
Received error message '{'requestId': '41e740ab-a499-4200-b476-3e195e026607', 'status': {'message': '{"requestId":"41e740ab-a499-4200-b476-3e195e026607","code":"UnsupportedOperationException"}', 'code': 498, 'attributes': {}}, 'result': {'data': None, 'meta': {}}}'

With results dictionary '{'41e740ab-a499-4200-b476-3e195e026607': <gremlin_python.driver.resultset.ResultSet object at 0x7f6659758c90>}
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data I could test on ?

Comment: I will send the query to insert these records.

Comment: Does it work if you change `values(‘mathResult’)` to `select(‘mathResult’).unfold())` ? If that works I can explain why in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the dataset using:

```
g.addV('Customer').
  property(T.id, '1').
  addV('Workspace').
  property(T.id, '2').
  property('lastUpdatedOn', 2000).
  property('createdOn', 1000).
  property('lastUpdatedOn_MN', 'March').
  addV('Workspace').
  property(T.id, '3').
  property('lastUpdatedOn', 4000).
  property('createdOn', 2000).
  property('lastUpdatedOn_MN', 'March').
  addV('Workspace').
  property(T.id, '4').
  property('lastUpdatedOn', 20000).
  property('createdOn', 10000).
  property('lastUpdatedOn_MN', 'April').
  addV('Workspace').
  property(T.id, '5').
  property('lastUpdatedOn', 40000).
  property('createdOn', 20000).
  property('lastUpdatedOn_MN', 'April').
  V().
  hasLabel('Workspace').
  addE('connected').from(__.V('1'))
```

And then I ran below query to get the desired sum.

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel('Customer').
......2>   out().
......3>   hasLabel('Workspace').
......4>   has('lastUpdatedOn').
......5>   has('createdOn').
......6>   project('gp1', 'var1', 'var2').
......7>     by(values('lastUpdatedOn_MN')).
......8>     by(values('createdOn')).
......9>     by(values('lastUpdatedOn')).
.....10>   project('mathResult', 'monthName').by(math('var2-var1')).by('gp1').
.....11>   group().by('monthName').by('mathResult').
.....12>   unfold().as('a').
.....13>   select(values).
.....14>   sum(local).
.....15>   group().by(select('a').select(keys)).by(unfold())
==>[March:3000.0,April:30000.0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to resolve the issue. Can i ask why is the unfold() step needed. Also why do we need to use the local within the sum() step.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. 
1. Sum(local) doesn't change the cardinality of the overall solution. If you have incoming 10 lists then the result is 10 lists each having sum of elements inside the input list. 
2. Unfold is needed because the values for group step are by default enclosed within a list. So if you dont have that unfold the result would look like: 
[March:[3000.0],April:[30000.0]]
If you are okay with this result, then you can remove that unfold.